# Subset observations by group for those closest to median of entire sample

Tags: r, subset

I have multiple sites - each visited multiple times. I would like to subset the data to include only a single visit from each site (but all observations from that visit) and I would like that visit to be closest (in time) to the median date of all visits to all sites.

Sample Data:

```
d = data.table(site = c('a', 'a','a','a','b', 'b','b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'), 
       sex = c('m','f','m','f','m','f','m','f','m','f','m','f'), 
       date = c(127,127, 185, 185, 132,132, 189,189, 119,119, 178, 178), 
       count = c(12, 15, 10, 9, 18, 22,12, 15, 10, 9, 18, 22))
```

What I would like to get:

```
d = data.table(site = c('a', 'a','b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), 
     sex = c('m','f','m','f','m','f'),
     date = c(127,127, 132,132, 178, 178), 
     count = c(12, 15,18, 22, 18, 22))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

d = data.table(site = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'),
               date = c(127, 185, 132, 189, 119, 178),
               count = c(12, 15, 10, 9, 18, 22))

d.median = d[, median(date)]
d[, {i = which.min(abs(date - d.median));
     list(date = date[i], count = count[i])},
  by = list(sex, site)]
```

Comment: I've edited my original question to address an additional complication I've come across.

Comment: it's not entirely obvious what you want - I made a change according to how I understand your question (that gives that result)

Comment: I was initially getting an error message:  Error in `[.data.frame`(d, , { : unused argument(s) (by = list(sex, site))                             I realized that the data was in a data frame rather than a data table and after that fix everything worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using `ave` and `rank` from base R

```
myRanks <- with(mydf, ave(date, site, FUN = function(x) 
  rank(abs(x - median(date)), ties.method = "first")))
mydf[myRanks == 1, ]
#   site date count
# 1    a  127    12
# 3    b  132    10
# 6    c  178    22
```

`rank` is used to help deal with cases where you might have more than one value "closest" to the median.